# how to auto increment a number everytime when a button is clicked on other page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form created using HTML and CSS, this form is not for submitting any data in fact it's only for printing purposes.

This form has an input field at top left corner to put a unique 6 digit number to uniquely identify each form.

On the homepage, there is a button link to that form page and I want to increment that serial no which is by default `000000` every time a link button to this form page is clicked.

**index.html:**

```
<a href="pages/form-1.html"></a>
```

**form-1.html:**

```
<input class="serial-no" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="000000" maxlength="6" size="6">
```

Comment: You will need to use some PHP, record how many clicks the button has (Which will get sent to the database) From here you can grab that data and display it as the number.

Comment: So you're redirecting to *form-1.html*, not opening it in a pop-up? Anyways, you should get familiar with `localStorage` (and `postMessage()` if working with pop-up) in order to achieve that without using a backend.

Comment: since i am new to php and javascript please can you help me with an example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution:

1. Using cookie
2. Using browser-session

**Note: Please comment another solution, while using one solution**

**main-page.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="form-1.html">Print</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**form-1.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Printing</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadNextSeqToForm()">
        <form>
            <input id="serial" class="serial-no" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="000000" maxlength="6" size="6">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        /*
        //Solution 1: Using Cookies
        function getNextSeq() {
           var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
           var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
           for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
               var c = ca[i];
               while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                   c = c.substring(1);//Trim the empty space if exists
               }
               if (c.indexOf("next") == 0) {
                var fragments = c.split("=");
                if(fragments.length == 2 && !isNaN(fragments[1])) {
                    return parseInt(fragments[1]) + 1;
                }
               }
           }
           return "1";//default
        } 
        function loadNextSeqToForm() {
           var nextValue = getNextSeq();
           document.cookie = "next=" + nextValue + ";";
           document.getElementById("serial").value = formatToSixCharacters(nextValue);
        } 

        function formatToSixCharacters(num) {
           var numStr = num + "";
           if(numStr.length < 6) {
               var zeros = 6 - numStr.length;
               for(var i = 1; i <= zeros; i++) {
                   numStr = "0" + numStr;
               }
            }
            return numStr;
        }
        */

        //Solution 2: Using Session
        function loadNextSeqToForm() {
            var nextValue = sessionStorage.getItem("next") != null? sessionStorage.getItem("next") : 1; 
            document.getElementById("serial").value = formatToSixCharacters(nextValue); 
            sessionStorage.setItem("next", parseInt(nextValue) + 1)
        } 

        function formatToSixCharacters(num) {
            var numStr = num + "";
            if(numStr.length < 6) {
                var zeros = 6 - numStr.length;
                for(var i = 1; i <= zeros; i++) {
                    numStr = "0" + numStr;
                }
            }
            return numStr;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

++ Code using PHP and MySQL

**main-page.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note this time we have to use PHP file reference -->
        <a href="form-1.php">Print</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**form-1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
function getNextSequnceNumber() {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "orders";
    $nextSeq = 1;
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT next_seq FROM order_sequence";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $nextSeq = $row["next_seq"];
        }
    }
    //Update next sequence number in db
    $sql = "UPDATE order_sequence SET next_seq = ".($nextSeq + 1);
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        //Updated successfully
        //Write in log may be
    }
    $conn->close();
    return formatToSixCharacters($nextSeq);
}
function formatToSixCharacters($num) {
    $numStr = $num . "";
    if(strlen($numStr) < 6) {
        $zeros = 6 - strlen($numStr);
        for($i = 1; $i <= $zeros; $i++) {
            $numStr = "0" . $numStr;
        }
    }
    return $numStr;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Printing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input class="serial-no" type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo getNextSequnceNumber() ?>" maxlength="6" size="6" readonly="readonly">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**DB Scripts**

```
CREATE DATABASE orders;
USE orders;
CREATE TABLE order_sequence (
    next_seq INT NOT NULL
);
-- DEFAULT VALUE
INSERT INTO order_sequence (next_seq)
    VALUES(1);
```

Note: Make sure you replace your DB user name and password

**SQLITE3 version of code as requested**

**form-sqlite.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
class DBUtil extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
        //Open db
        $this->open("orders.db");
    }

    function createTableIfNotExists() {
        //create table if not exists already
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_sequence ("
            ."    next_seq INT NOT NULL"
            .")";
        $result = $this->exec($sql);
        return $result;//Whether table created successfully or not
    }

    function updateNextSeqNumber($nextSeq) {
        //update next sequnce number in db
        $sql = "UPDATE order_sequence SET next_seq = ".$nextSeq;
        $result = $this->exec($sql);
        return $result;
    }

    function insertFirstTime() {
        //insert first time
        $sql = "INSERT INTO order_sequence (next_seq) VALUES (1)";
        $result = $this->exec($sql);
        return $result;
    }

    function getNextSeq() {
        //get next sequence number
        $sql = "SELECT next_seq FROM order_sequence";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $nextSeq = 1;
        if($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
            $nextSeq = $row["next_seq"];
        } else {
            $this->insertFirstTime();//First sequence number, so that next update queries will be always successfull
        }
        $this->updateNextSeqNumber($nextSeq + 1);
        return $nextSeq;
    }
}

function getNextSequnceNumber() {
    //Create new object of utility class
    $db = new DBUtil();
    if(!$db){
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->lastErrorMsg());
    }
    //Check if connected
    if($db->createTableIfNotExists()) {
        $nextSeq = $db->getNextSeq();
        return formatToSixCharacters($nextSeq);
    } else {
        die ("Error: " . $db->lastErrorMsg());
    }
    //close connection finally
    $db->close();
}

function formatToSixCharacters($num) {
    $numStr = $num . "";
    if(strlen($numStr) < 6) {
        $zeros = 6 - strlen($numStr);
        for($i = 1; $i <= $zeros; $i++) {
            $numStr = "0" . $numStr;
        }
    }
    return $numStr;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Printing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input class="serial-no" type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo getNextSequnceNumber() ?>" maxlength="6" size="6" readonly="readonly">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**++PHPDesktop With Sqlite Version**

**form-php-desktop-sqlite.php**

Please include this PHPDesktop Helper file [pdo.php](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/blob/master/var/pdo.php) provided by PHPDesktop. However this is small helper file, it does not serve big purpose, but it will help you for now.

Also read Using [Sqlite with PHP Desktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Using-SQLite)

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./pdo.php";

function getNextSequnceNumber() {
    //Open connection
    $db_file = "./orders.sqlite3";
    PDO_Connect("sqlite:$db_file");
    //Create table if not exists
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_sequence ("
        ."    next_seq INT NOT NULL"
        .")";
    PDO_Execute($sql);

    //get next sequence number
    $sql = "SELECT next_seq FROM order_sequence";
    $nextSeq = PDO_FetchOne($sql);
    if($nextSeq == null) {
        $nextSeq = 1;
        //Also insert first time record
        $sql = "INSERT INTO order_sequence (next_seq) VALUES (1)";
        PDO_Execute($sql);
    }
    //Update next time sequence
    $sql = "UPDATE order_sequence SET next_seq = ".($nextSeq + 1);
    PDO_Execute($sql);
    return formatToSixCharacters($nextSeq);
}

function formatToSixCharacters($num) {
    $numStr = $num . "";
    if(strlen($numStr) < 6) {
        $zeros = 6 - strlen($numStr);
        for($i = 1; $i <= $zeros; $i++) {
            $numStr = "0" . $numStr;
        }
    }
    return $numStr;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Printing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input class="serial-no" type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo getNextSequnceNumber() ?>" maxlength="6" size="6" readonly="readonly">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn more about browser session usage [here from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Learn more about browser cookies usage [here from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: thanks for your kind answer solution 1 is working but some how solution 2 is not working please check this if possiable. browser session is not an option for me since it destroy session on browser exit. i want a solution that doesn't revert serial no back to default on browser exit.

Comment: @Aqeel-Arcade you are right. The cookie method will work if you add expiration period with longer interval. But Session method will work only till browser is alive. If you are willing to persist which should never change, you should use database for storing the above sequence number or using Server session. If you will let me know which technology you are using for server end like (Java/PHP) I will write solution accordingly to help.

Comment: thanks for reply, i am using php as server side language.

Comment: For PHP I have provided the working code. Please check and let me know.

Comment: thanks again for your kind answer. since i am using phpdesktop chrome for my application i don't afford to use mysql instead i want to use sqlite with pdo interface. can you please modify above code so it work in this environment! thanks in advance.

Comment: In PHP Sqlite functions are also similar to MySQL. Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php , you just need to replace the MySQL functions with Sqlite functions. I hope this helps you.

Comment: can you edit this code so it work with sqlite cause i am new to sqlite!

Comment: Hi have updated my answer for SQLITE specific code. This time I have given it name **form-sqlite.php**, so make sure you give **form-sqlite.php** file reference in **main-page.html** file. I hope now you will be happy!! :)

Comment: it gives me an error on form-1.php page on line 4  **Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\Users\SKY\Desktop\testing\www\form1.php on line 4** please help me.

Comment: Sorry you may have confused because I gave **form-sqlite.html** name, I have updated my answer, the file name should be **form-sqlite.php**. Now you do not need to use **form-1.php**, In **main-page.html** file update `<a href="form-sqlite.php">Print</a>`. And put the **form-sqlite.php** file in same folder as **main-page.html** inside your **www** directory. It will work fine.

Comment: actually i rename the **form-sqlite.php** to **form1.php** and also updated its link in the **main-page.html** and still got this error!

Comment: Could you give the environment details, PHP version, Server etc., Because I have tested this code with PHP 5.3 in XAMPP, it worked fine.

Comment: I can help with chat, or skype chat; if you want.

Comment: of course! why not, please share your skype details.

Comment: i am using php 5.6 in phpdesktop chrome.

Comment: Please check my updated answer as per you provided the information. If still you face problem, you can ping me in SKYPE.

Comment: i think i have some sqlite installation issues! i am using phpliteadmin to manage sqlite databae but comes with these errors.                                        **PDO: installed**                                                                                                       **PDO SQLite Driver: not installed**                                                                     **SQLite3: not installed**                                                                                           **SQLiteDatabase: not installed**

Comment: By default SQLite is ena led in PHPDesktop. You can double check whether SQLite is enabled in your case, if not enavle it and then test. Check `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do this is by using **jQuery**. Use the **click event listener** with the button link which will listen to every clicks made to that button, and increment the value with each clicks. With the starting value as 000000, store the incremented value into a variable and then use that variable on a desired page.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**
Consider that you have this button on the **home.html** page:

```
<a href="formpage.html" id="linkcounter">BUTTON</a>
```

Now, using jQuery - listen to the click events from this link and store the incremented values on variable like this:

```
var count = 0,
    default = '000000';
$('#linkcounter').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count++;
    var ctxt = '' + count;
    var incrementval = pad.substr(0, pad.length - ctxt.length) + ctxt;
});

// store the value into the local storage of DOM for the current session. this is done to retain the variable value even after a page is refreshed.
var incrementvallocal = incrementval;
localStorage.setItem("incrementvalueper", incrementvallocal);
```

The incremented value stored in the variable `incrementval` is sent to the localstorage. Now just use the value of this variable on desired page(in this example it is **formpage.html**).

If you want to set the placeholder text on the form page which has an input field like this:

```
<input class="serial-no" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="000000" maxlength="6" size="6">
```

by the incremented value, then use this jQuery code:

```
// get incremented value from the local storage of DOM.
var getincval = localStorage.getItem("incrementvalueper");

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.serial-no').attr("placeholder", getincval);
});
```

This code uses the value of the variable `getincval`(which has the incremented click value) and sets it to the placeholder text of the `input` element which has the class `.serial-no`.

Let me know if this helps. :)